# Issues migrating SQL Server 2008 to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm working to migrate an existing SQL Server 2008 database (on-premises) to Azure SQL. I'm able to generate a .dacpac file using Visual Studio. When I try to import the .dacpac file into Azure SQL, I get the following error:

```
Operation Name: Performs a database extension operation.
Error: The storage URI is not valid.
```

So far, I've verified that there are no spaces in the filename & the account does have permissions.

Any pointers to resolving this issue is appreciated.

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this? Presumably you've tried every returned from a [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%3A+The+storage+URI+is+not+valid.)..?

Comment: Will update the question with this.

Comment: @Rajesh what's the your dacpac file name?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, is the error solved now? If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some one get the same error which caused by the .bacpac file name contains a space. Please check it you have the same problem: Ref here: [Error "The storage URI is not valid" when creating a new SQL Azure database from a bacpac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854221/error-the-storage-uri-is-not-valid-when-creating-a-new-sql-azure-database-from).

I don't what your system is, if you are use windows system, please try to use the “**deploy the database to SQL Azure**” option from the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to deploy the local SQL database to Azure. It's much easier.

[image]

Ref this tutorial: https://developer.relatude.com/deploying-a-sql-database-to-azure-with-sql-server-management-studio.